# HTML/CSS Firefox requires multiple refreshs to load all the images

Tags: image, firefox, loading

I recently coded a website, the code is valid xHTML 1.0 strict.

The problem occurs in firefox 12 and I believe other versions.When I load the site the first time, it doesn't load +- half images.I hit refresh and it loads more, after ~5 refreshes it load's completely.

I clear the cookies and the same happens.

Where could be the problem, why doesn't it load completely on the first loading ?

Website: http://tinyurl.com/7ropf8c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in your server.  For a bunch of the images it returns a "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this by preloading the images

http://elouai.com/javascript-preload-images.php

Comment: That's not how I work man.No one ought to work like that.You don't hide your mistakes by putting extra code, you find and remove the mistakes.That's what I'm trying to do.

I put a lot of images in empty html file and it all loaded in FF including big ones.There is clearly problem in my code which stops loading images in the middle of the process which I try to find.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough it was a hosting issue.I have no idea how, but I asked my friend to upload files to his hosting and it works fine there.